# Drop rows with multiple conditions on columns

Tags: python, pandas

I want to drop rows on many condition. Below is the code but it takes a lot of time.

```
a=[]
for i in range(len(df)):
    if df['col_1'][i] in ['a','b'] and (pd.isna(df['col_2'][i])==True or df['col_2'][i]=='c'):
        a.append(i)

df.drop(a, inplace=True)
df.reset_index(inplace=True,drop=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with `invert` conditions - here `isin` to `~`, `|` to `&`,`&` to `|`, `isna` to `notna` and `==` to `!=`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
         'col_1':list('abgaeb'),
         'col_2':[np.nan,'c','d','c','f',np.nan],

})

m = (~df['col_1'].isin(['a','b'])) | df['col_2'].notna() & (df['col_2'] !='c')

df = df[m]
print (df)
  col_1 col_2
2     g     d
4     e     f
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`df = df.loc[~(df['col_1'].isin(['a','b']) & ((pd.isna(df['col_2'])==True) | (df['col_2']=='c')))]`